# How to overwrite Woocommerce translations

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, translation

I'm using Woocommerce in a spanish WordPress website. There are two words that I'd like to change from Woocomerce spanish translation. I change them in the .po file (in wp-content/languages/plugins/) and it works, but whenever I upgrade the plugin and its translations, this file is overwritten and I loose my translations.

I've read the Woocommerce docs (section "Making your Localization upgrade safe"), but it just says where the .po file should be, and I'm respecting this.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there any way to overwrite these translations with mine, so they keep unchanged when I upgrade Woocommerce?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a child theme, please follow these recommendations:
[https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/295729/160417](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/295729/160417)

Answer (score 5):

["Making your Localization upgrade safe" section](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-localization/) is correct, but it say nothing about filename - it must be with woocommerce- prefix, not just es_ES.mo.

So your solution is:

> wp-content/languages/woocommerce/woocommerce-es_ES.mo

Comment: That's the filename I have.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid overwriting, you should move your translations to /wp-content/languages/woocommerce/